# How do I display data in a table and allow users to copy selected data?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a long list of data that I want to display in table format to users. The data changes when the user performs certain actions in my app, but it is not directly editable. So the user can create a reasonably big table of data, but he can't change individual cells' values.

However, I do want the data to be copy-able. So I want it to be possible for the user to select some or all of the cells, and do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the data to his clipboard, and then a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the data to an external text editor.

At the moment, I'm displaying the data in a ListView with a GridView and this works perfectly, except that GridView doesn't allow one to copy data.

What other options can I try? Ours is a WPF app, coding in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trythe DataGrid control of the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535). It allows you to copy the data on the grid and paste it anywhere (like notepad, word, etc.). You can bind a datasource there the way you do on DataGridView\DataGrid controls on .Net Win App and Web App application.

Comment: @cfouche - Thanks actually we have simillar requirements and ours was solve by using the WPF Toolkit.